# how to click a check box from its id with a certain key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want to make a script that clicks a checkbox when I press the 'c' key. Can somebody show me how to do this or if it's simple, make one?This is what I want it to do.

```
$("#cHideChat").click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this. This fires when you press `c`

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which == 67){
    $("#check")[0].click()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
```

If you want to make it work only if the checkbox is unchecked :

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which == 67){
    if($("#check").prop("checked") == false){
     $("#check")[0].click()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
```

Comment: thank you dude it worked. do you know how to make it click only if the box is unchecked. so it only changes its value if it is not checked

Comment: Edited my answer @SaladTato-Agario

Comment: how to do i change the option to work for it being checked. do i use 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Change `false` to `true` @SaladTato-Agario

Comment: Click "Show code snippet" @SaladTato-Agario or try reloading the page

Comment: it works now but the script doesnt. i miss worded the question so i will make a new question tommorow but thanks for the first keypress script that works.

Comment: Okay @SaladTato-Agario

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check the checkbox, you need to use,

```
$("#cHideChat").prop("checked",true);
```

Your code will search for the jquery click event handler. ie it will call the click event handler only if you wrote a click handler using jquery.

If you really want to emulate the click on that checkbox, you need to use the dom element click,

```
$("#cHideChat")[0].click();
```

Comment: how can i trigger this with a certain key?

Comment: use this one $("#cHideChat")[0].click();

Comment: the code i used worked but im saying that i want to trigger it using a certain key on my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little sample of when the user deselects the checkbox. Hope this is what you're looking for. Goodluck!

**EDIT**

the function only fires if the user presses c and the checkbox is unchecked if it is checked the function wont fire

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e){
 if(!$('#check').is(':checked')) {
     if(e.which == 67){
    $("#check")[0].click()
  }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check below code

```
    $( "#cHideChat").keypress(function( event ) {
          if ( event.which == 99 ) {
              $("#cHideChat").click()
             //event.preventDefault();  
          }
    });
```